# How, using code-only, do I map Vertical Inheritance using multiple, existing "type" values? (Telerik OpenAccess)

Tags: c#, orm, telerik

I am trying to map a vertical inheritance between a base class and derived class (obviously). I am using code-only and the FluentAPI approach for which I have found almost ZERO documentation. I have found a couple of docs on vertical inheritance and code-only but very few on managing the discriminator column/value.

S​o ​I have been trying to extrapolate how to do it from a combination of this [blog post](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/defining-hierarchical-domain-models---part-one) and some documentation on [implementing vertical inheritance](http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/developers-guide/code-only-mapping/inheritance/fluent-mapping-inheritance-vertical) using code-only. All to no avail.

[image]

You will see that I have a "*Deliverables*" base table and "*PrintDeliverables*" derives from that. There will be other derivatives coming down the road. But I figured I would start with one first.

Anyway, I naturally have models that map to the tables.

```
public class PrintDeliverable : BDeliverableBase
{
    public String PaperItemNumber { get; set; }

    public String PrinterModel { get; set; }

    public Boolean? ColorOption { get; set; }

    public String ProductCode { get; set; }

}   

public class BDeliverableBase : BModelBase, IDeliverable, ISingleID
{
    public Int64 ID { get; set; }

    public String Label { get; set; }

    public String Description { get; set; }

    public IList<DeliverableAttribute> Attributes { get; set; }

    public Int64 TypeID { get; set; }
    public DeliverableType Type { get; set; }

}

public class DeliverableType : BModelBase, ISingleID
{

    public Int64 ID { get; set; }

    public String Label { get; set; }

    public String Description { get; set; }

    public IList<BDeliverableBase> Deliverables { get; set; }
}
```

I have standard mapping which maps the fields and types, sizes, etc. When I run it with no further additions I get the Error ...

```
Invalid Column name voa_class
```

My research uncovered that the ORM is attempting to update a "discriminator" column with a value that will tie the base table and table with the derived data together. I learned that I can change the name of the column it uses, which I did in the BASE CLASS mapping (BDeliverableBase). I changed it to use the "DeliverableTypeId" column  since the DeliverableType indicates which TYPE of deliverable it is. Since each TYPE will have it's own derivative table this would be an appropriate value to associate which derivative table to use.

```
MappingConfiguration<BDeliverableBase> map = new MappingConfiguration<BDeliverableBase>();
map.HasDiscriminator().ToColumn("DeliverableTypeId");
```

It appears to like this better but it wants to insert this crazy number (ex// 612274703-854) into the DeliverableTypeId column which, of course, being a foreign key to the DeliverableTypes table is not allowed.

```
Insert of '612274703-' failed: Telerik.OpenAccess.RT.sql.SQLException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_DeliverableType". The conflict occurred in database "DB1", table "dbo.DeliverableTypes", column 'DeliverableTypeId'
```

I learned that OpenAccess/DataAccess generates a hash value to insert into the discriminator column. I do not want this, in fact I know that the value must be one of the IDs available in the DeliverableType. So I read in [one of the docs](http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/developers-guide/code-only-mapping/inheritance/fluent-mapping-inheritance-advanced-properties#how-to:-set-advanced-properties-Discriminator) that you could define what value to assign to the discriminator. The example applied a hard-coded value to the base class (dog and cat derived from animal) ...

```
animal.HasDiscriminatorValue("23");
```

This presented one problem ... I do not have a ***single*** value I can hard-code. It could one of MANY values present in the *DeliverableTypes* table. However, for the sake of proving out the concept I hard-coded the value of an existing record

```
MappingConfiguration<BDeliverableBase> map = new MappingConfiguration<BDeliverableBase>();
map.HasDiscriminator().ToColumn("DeliverableTypeId");
map.HasDiscriminatorValue("819");
```

I continued to get the identical error from before. So it doesn't appear that it was applying my hard-coded value. So ... I thought, while hard-coding the value is a little hacky it would make more sense to define that in the mapping for the ***derived*** class. That would resolve my hard-coded issue since ALL instances of that derived class WOULD indeed be of the same DeliverableTypeId. So I tried ...

```
MappingConfiguration<BDeliverableBase> map = new MappingConfiguration<BDeliverableBase>();
map.HasDiscriminator().ToColumn("DeliverableTypeId");


MappingConfiguration<PrintDeliverable> map = new MappingConfiguration<PrintDeliverable>();
map.HasDiscriminatorValue("819");
```

This resulted in the Error

```
Insert of '612274703-857' failed: Telerik.OpenAccess.RT.sql.SQLException: String or binary data would be truncated.
```

So I got a different error but still the same poblem. This type it was trying to stuff the ORM generated discriminator value (instead of my 819) into what I am assuming is my defined discriminator column (DeliverableTypeId), although the different error makes me suspicious that it was targeting a different column.(?)

In an effort to not drag this out too long I have tried several combinations of where to these "HasDiscriminator" and "HasDiscriminatorValue" assignments go but always end up with one or the other of these errors. So the question is ...

**How, using code-only, do I map Vertical Inheritance using multiple, existing "type" values?**